# DataSource.setLoginTimeout and DriverManager.setLoginTimeout global?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

When I set the login timeout on the data source, what does it do? Does it call DriverManager.setLoginTimeout() under the hood? Asking this because I'm curious as to whether it's genuinely possible to set a per-data source login time out. Say if I have different DBMSs that I want to connect to, and these DBs have different responsiveness, so it's reasonable to expect a different allowance for connection timeout, right?

If the answer is yes, then is there a good reason the DriverManager.setLoginTimeot() method is static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property should be per `DataSource` (although as far as I can see there is no explicit mention of this in the JDBC spec). The DataSource implementation of some drivers don't even use DriverManager when creating connections.

Be aware though that the value set on the DriverManager will need to be explicitly used by the driver, as DriverManager itself does nothing with the value (except store it). For example the PostgreSQL driver only uses the DriverManager value if no explicit timeout was configured in the JDBC url, Properties object or DataSource properties.

The reason for `DriverManager.setLoginTimeout()` is that you do not control which Driver is actually being used by the DriverManager(*) so the only way to control it is through the DriverManager.

(*) except of course by the drivers you added to the classpath (and in Java 5 or earlier: which you explicitly loaded).

Comment: Thank you. I'm been googling around trying to find the proper syntax to specify the loginTimeout property on the url for oracle and sql server connections, but haven't been able to. Would you happen to have a pointer?

Comment: Well, according to [this Oracle Driver page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jdbc_drivers/oracle.html#1066403) the driver supports `LoginTimeout` as property and same for the [SQl Server driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms378988%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx). This btw took me a few seconds to google.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question is how do I link these name value pairs into the url? These docs aren't that clear about that. Do I just append my url with ";LoginTimeout=10"? Say if my current url is "jdbc:oracle:thin:@DB_INSTANCE", do I just change it to "jdbc:oracle:thin:@DB_INSTANCE;LoginTimeout=10"? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still unable to figure out how to do it. If I set my url to jdbc:oracle:thin:@MyDBTnsname&loginTimeout=10, it'll complain with the message "Could not resolve the connect identifier "MyDBTnsname@loginTimeout=10"

Comment: Not 100% sure about Oracle JDBC URLs, but you usually separate JDBC properties from the rest of the URL with a `?`, so this would be : `jdbc:oracle:thin:@MyDBTnsname?loginTimeout=10` (further properties are separated using `&`. And other wise you need to use the method which accepts a `Properties` object and put the driver properties in that `Properties` object.

Comment: Tried the question mark. No dice. Thanks though. The reason I'm asking this question is really for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306896/dbcp-connection-pool-logintimeout